# Check if file has been changed on dynamic website

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, web-scraping

I am writing a function, which downloads a zip file from a website every single day, only if the file has been updated. Is there any way for me to find if the file has been changed without downloading it? There is also a table generated on the same website, so I was thinking, check if there are new values in the table, if true, then download the file.
Is there any other approach I could find useful? Unfortunately, I cannot publish the website I am downloading the file form.

Comment: Depends on what the server supports. If it accepts conditional headers like `If-Modified-Since` or `If-None-Match`, or at least outputs `Last-Modified` HTTP hearers or such, that would be the way to do it.

Comment: The only way to do it really is to check for changes (either downloading the file or looking for something on a page that you know changes in step with changes to the file) or for the site to provide some kind of API that tells you if it has changed. If the site has a sitemap xml file then potentially that might list the last modified date for a page that changes in step with the file, but it would reflect *any* change to the page so it might not be useful for you (and might not even be updated properly anyway - sitemap files are often neglected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the website you are requesting resource from implements Etag and Conditional request you make use of this to fetch the resource.

Steps:

- Request resource /resource, save Etag Header
- Again request content but with If-None-Match=[saved-etag]. If the etag has changed server will 200 OK with content otherwise 304 (Not modified).
- You may try HEAD requests to get only the headers of the content and compare with the already saved headers to decide whether the content has changed or not.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-None-Match